# Непонятные подсказки в VS Code для JavaScript. Как отключить IntelliSense в Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Проверил, из плагинов ничего такого не установлено, но в JS постоянно вылазят эти подсказки. Как их отключить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отключить можно. Но у вас просто что-то сбилось. Не пробовали переустановить VS Code? Они сегодня очередное обновление «выкатили» [July 2017 (version 1.15)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_15).

Comment: странно, ищет по буквам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался с проблеймой. Оказалось, что при синтаксической ошибке он показывает такие странные подсказки, если написать `document.getElementById` - тогда подсказки нормальные. Странно как-то, но все же. Вопрос снят.

Answer (score 0):

**Customizing IntelliSense** — https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense

> Вы можете изменить эти параметры в своем `settings.json` файле, как
>   описано в [разделе «Параметры пользователя и рабочей области»](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).

```js
{
    "editor.quickSuggestions": false
}
```

---

- [How to disable IntelliSense in VS Code for Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911977/prevent-autocomplete-in-visual-studio-code) (англ.)